# google chart - Assigning random colors to data

Tags: php, charts, google-visualization

My code is:

```
['checkio','money'],
<?php   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($que)){ ?>
['<?php echo $row['checkio']?>' , <?php echo $row['money']?>],
<?php } ?>
```

According to my sources I should use a loop.
The problem with using a loop is that it cannot specify a separate color..

Its result is:

```
['checkio','money']
['in',1000]
['out',200]
```

all the data are the same color.
So, What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure which chart are you using, but if you are drawing the chart with javascript,  you can set a series color in the options of the chart. Here is an example:

```
var options = {};

function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}    

options.series={};
for(var i = 0;i < data.getNumberOfRows();i++){
    options.series[i]={color:getRandomColor()}
}
```

Full example: http://jsfiddle.net/z2ewqoe1/